# footer disappears when showing products in home page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I just installed magento 1.9.0.1 and it comes with the rwd theme.
Tried to list products from a category. The product shows up but the footer part completely disappears.

```
<div class="page-title"> <h2>Our Latest Products</h2> </div> <p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>
```

Before..
[image]

After..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the rwd theme has a few (read "a lot of") issues.
The template `catalog/product/list.phtml` cannot be used anymore outside of a category page context, or search page because of this code:

```
<?php
$_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`$this->getChild('name.after')` returns `null` and there is an error when calling `getSortedChildren` on `null`.

the code above should be wrapped in an if statement.

```
<?php
if ($this->getChild('name.after')) : 
    $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
        ?>
        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
 <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the footer, your page is not loaded due an error. I think it is in list.phtml. to find the error please change this in your index.php

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

So you can see the error.